# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: Read Image pixel data using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using PIL to get image pixel data and store it to an array but it is giving following error.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

image_data = []

path = "plasmodium_images/"
for i in os.listdir("images"):
        Image.open(path+i)
```

error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
6 path = "plasmodium_images/"
      7 for i in os.listdir("plasmodium_images"):
----> 8         Image.open(path+i)

c:\users\csvankhede\anaconda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2310 
   2311     if filename:
-> 2312         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2313 
   2314     try:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'plasmodium_images/plasmodium-phone-0001.jpg'
```

I have tried changing mode and giving full path also but it doesn't work.

`.png` can be opened but it doesn't work for `.jpg` images.

Comment: Why does the code you posted say `path="images/"` but the error says `path="plasmodium_images/"` ?

Comment: Sry that was edit problem, I have edited the question. and it is solved now. My previous code created an empty file of the given image name. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code from a command prompt that you are running as an administrator. Right click "command prompt" from the start menu and click "Run as Administrator."

Comment: same error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

Comment: @ChhayaVankhede Please add additional information to the question by editing it.